# Deprecated SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, are there any work-arounds?

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I don't really have any problem with the code. It just bothers me that there's a deprecation in my Java class. Are there any alternatives? It seems there may be incompatibilities with the API level. Same deprecation issue goes with `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`. 
Is there any available alternative to this (with at least, making the code deprecation-free) or there is really none as of the moment?

Comment: Why are you trying to keep the screen on using a `WakeLock`, instead of `setKeepScreen()`, `android:keepScreenOn`, `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, etc.? As the documentation states, "Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission." What are you trying to achieve that isn't supported this way?

Comment: For example, keeping the screen on even if you go to anoher app. I am considering this because of the bug in some handsets that prevents accelerometer updates with the screen off even if you have a foreground service with a partial wakelock adquired.